# Sitewide % Off Promotion to show discount on PDP

Tags: discount, promotions

We are creating a 10% off sitewide promotion. Some items are at original price others are at a discount. How would we need to setup the promotion if we wanted the 10% off price to reflect on the Product Detail Page whether the item is at original price or at a discounted price? We want the 10% to display off of the lowest price and show on the PDP without having to add the item to the cart.

Also, we would also in this instance like to be able to exclude items that are not applicable.

Comment: Please add more information about problem and what you already tried. Also mention version of magento.

Comment: The problem is that we send emails about these promotions and the emails have multiple items in them, some original price some discounted. Let's say the discount is 50% off. If the item is original price $100 we would strike through that in the email and put the sale price of $50 - WE WANT THIS SAME THING TO BE REFLECTED ON THE PDP.

Comment: If the item in the email is all ready discounted, like Orig. is $100, sale price is $80, 50% off the $80 would be $40, so in the email we would put Orig. $100 strike through that and put $40 - WE WANT THIS SAME THING TO BE REFLECTED ON THE PDP.

Comment: And for the items that should not apply at all, we'd like to exclude them from the discount all together. Is this possible, if so how?

Comment: We don't want the customer to have to add the item to the cart, then go to the cart to see the discounted price. It's not a good customer experience, especially since no coupon code is needed in this promotion.